# Rewrite SEO friendly url

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2

How can I rewrite url `category/index?id=1` to `fenlei/pingmiansheji` in Yii 2?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read well documented [Yii2 routing guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question is answered numerous times, and is well documented in Yii2 official documents. Try to solve your own problem first, and then ask when you're stuck - explaining what you've tried, and what the error is. Check the docs for `routing` and possibly also `sluggable behavior`.

Answer (score 1):

if your point is show another url with pretty url you can user this:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'fenlei/pingmiansheji /<id:\d+>'=>'category/index',
        ],
```